# How to properly convert a UTF8 truetype font to use on web?

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I'm trying to embed this UTF8 truetype font (the font contains Persian characters) in the web and I use [this service](http://www.font2web.com/) to convert it to proper formats.
The only problem is, it's not working on Google Chrome. Firefox and IE display the font correctly.
[Here is the converted package.](http://ge.tt/8zjMDbH/v/0)
[And this is the original font.](http://ge.tt/7HBlDbH/v/0)

Answer (score 1):

I've converted the mentioned font in your question and uploaded it in the following Internet address:

[Mj_Dinar One Light Web Font Package](http://www.files.com/shared/527266d9c5624/mj_dinarOneLight.zip)

Also, You must use the following Style Lines:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourDesiredName';
    src: url('yourDesiredPathForFont/mj_dinar_one_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('yourDesiredPathForFont/mj_dinar_one_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('yourDesiredPathForFont/mj_dinar_one_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('yourDesiredPathForFont/mj_dinar_one_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('yourDesiredPathForFont/mj_dinar_one_light-webfont.svg#yourDesiredName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and, you should add the following lines in the **.htaccess** file:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```